# Visualize Titan graph

Tags: angular, titan

I have some product categories and their associated information data stored in Titan graph database. For example, consider the Amazon Web site which has the 1000s of products stored category wise.

For example, if I have to store Lenovo Original Mobile Charger, I will have it stored as below:

```
Electronics
  Cameras & Photography
    Accessories
      Batteries & Chargers
        Lenovo Original Mobile Charger
```

I want to visualize this kind of data in my Angular 2 application. How can go about a solution to this?

Comment: As a side note, please consider switching to [JanusGraph](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph). JanusGraph is a recent, actively maintained fork of Titan; Titan hasn't been updated since 2015.

Answer (score 1):

> **Note:** Titan is no longer maintained, you should switch to [JanusGraph](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph), which was forked from Titan and is maintained by an active community of users and developers.

There are several Gremlin-compatible visualization tools in Javascript that you can use with Angular, e.g.,

- [Graphexp](https://github.com/bricaud/graphexp)
- [KeyLines](https://cambridge-intelligence.com/visualizing-janusgraph-new-titandb-fork/) by Cambridge Intelligence
- [Ogma](https://doc.linkurio.us/ogma/latest/tutorials/janusgraph/) and [Linkurious Enterprise](https://linkurio.us/solution/janusgraph/) by Linkurious